# Line passing through origin in $\mathbb{C}^2$ where all numbres $\{z_i\}$ belong to same component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \ell$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z_1, \dots, z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ be such that$${1\over{z_1}} + \dots + {1\over{z_n}} = 0.$$Is there a line $\ell$ passing through the origin of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ such that all the numbers $z_1, \dots, z_n$ belong to the same component (open half-plane) of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \ell$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this answer in another question, but for the sake of future users looking up similar questions I will post this answer here.

Note that $z_k^{-1}$ is the vector with magnitude $|z_k|^{-1}$ and the direction as the conjugate of $z_k^{-1}$, i.e. reflected across the $x$ axis. So if you could write such a line $\mathcal l$ then you could have a line $l_2$ cutting off all $z_k^{-1}$ to one half-plane. Then clearly their sum cannot be zero - the component of each term with respect to the orthogonal of $l_2$ is positive.

Answer (score 2):

It's false : consider $z_1=1, z_2=-1, z_3=i, z_4=-i$. Then you have 
$$\frac{1}{z_1}+\frac{1}{z_2}+\frac{1}{z_3}+\frac{1}{z_4}=1-1-i+i=0$$ and you can see that no one line will verify your assertion.

Comment: This doesn't show that the statement is false in general though.

Comment: No indeed. But I thought that the question was to establish this assertion in all the cases.

Comment: @Baloown No, the question was to establish what the answer is in all cases which is, indeed, that it is false in every case.