# Does exist line passing through origin in $\mathbb{C}^2$ where all numbres $\{z_i\}$ belong to same component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \ell$, redux.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502586/line-passing-through-origin-in-mathbbc2-where-all-numbres-z-i-belong).

Let $z_1, \dots, z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ be such that $${1\over{z_1}} + \dots + {1\over{z_n}} = 0.$$How do I see that there does not exist a line $\ell$ passing through the origin of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ such that all the numbers $z_1, \dots, z_n$ belong to the same component (open half-plane) of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \ell$ for all $n$? Note that this is asking a different question than the linked question.

Comment: I am probably overlooking something obvious, but I do not see how your question is different from the referenced question  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502586/line-passing-through-origin-in-mathbbc2-where-all-numbres-z-i-belong.

Comment: What is the $\mathbb C ^2$ business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $z_k^{-1}$ is the vector with magnitude $|z_k|^{-1}$ and the direction as the conjugate of $z_k^{-1}$, i.e. reflected across the $x$ axis. So if you could write such a line $\mathcal l$ then you could have a line $l_2$ cutting off all $z_k^{-1}$ to one half-plane. Then clearly their sum cannot be zero - the component of each term with respect to the orthogonal of $l_2$ is positive.